# jQuery: Why does .width() sometimes return 0 after inserting elements with .html()?

Tags: jquery

I am getting some html and inserting it with `.html()`, after which I am trying to get the width of one of newly inserted elements with `.width()` (which has a CSS rule). However *sometimes* - the width is not picked up, and is returned as 0.

Is it because JS runs "ahead" of newly created elements and their css? I have tried chaining with `.html('...').find('...').width()` but it still sometimes does not work. What's the reason and is there a work around?

**Edit:** By popular demand, EXAMPLE:

```
/* ajax.response is:
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box width-A">test 1</div>
        <div class="box width-B">test 2</div>
        <div class="box width-C">test 3</div>
    </div> */

var boxOutput = $('.boxOutput'); /* .boxOutput is already on the page */
boxOutput.html(ajax.response);

// make width of ".boxes" equal to the sum of all ".box"

var boxWidth = 0;
$('.box', boxOutput).each(function(i) {
    boxWidth += $(this).width(); /* this is where sometimes width returns 0 */
});
$('.boxes', boxOutput).css('width', boxWidth);
```

My original code is too long/ugly to copy/paste, but this is a simplified exact thing I am doing (Sorry if there's a silly mistake somewhere, it's too late where I am :P). After getting html back from ajax, putting it into a div, I want to get width of each box (because it might be different), and then use that width. Again, 90% of the time, the width is returned correctly. It's those 10% when sometimes width is 0 :(

Comment: Can you show the exact code which is returning 0 with? Also, which browsers?

Comment: Are there images inside of the element? Are you also testing with WebKit?

Comment: If the element in question is an image, then the zero value will be returned as long as the image hasn't finished loading...

Comment: @alex, posted a copy of code. there is no images inside. testing with just firefox 4 on mac. works 90% of the time... wondering what is happening with those 10%.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, no images inside, just boring old divs :P

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Depends on what browser. Occasionally I find something will break with the synchronous rendering expectations of the javascript runtime and I'll need to get the result on the next tick.

I'd try:

```
$(elem).html(data);
setTimeout(function(){
    // Get the width here
},0);
```

Comment: Hi Josh, I guess there's some racing condition. Out of all the things, your setTimeout way seems to work for me. I guess not the most optimal solution, but it works! It's also nice to know I am not the only one with this weird behavior happening, hehe. Thank you :)

Comment: Confirmation that I see this intermittent behavior in Chrome 26.0.1410.64. Sometimes when showing a complicated dialog box for the first time, width() returns 0 (for an element that has been inserted into the DOM dynamically during dialog creation), but most of the time returns the correct width. Must be a race condition.

Comment: for 10 years I have avoided using setTimeout to compensate for browser/js holdup problems ... ... I never realized you could use a 0 for the time though .... very nice.

Comment: ... this technique should be built into people's img load scripts .. see [common example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Comment: In my case, it was because I was fading in a Bootstrap modal with a call to modal('show'), and then trying to manipulate the image width. But I forgot that during the fade animation, the element still isn't visible!

Comment: What a horrible hack! Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 14):

jQuery will return a zero width if the element is not visible. For example, I was having the same issue with an item being inserted onto a hidden form tab. Temporarily assigning it to the body, where it was visible, I was able to determine the width:

```
$("body").append(el); // First assign it to the body so that it's visible
var width = el.width(); // The width will now be correct
wrapper.append(el); // Now place the element where you want it.
```

One caveat is that if the element inherits different styling when assigned to the body then the width may not be correct.

Comment: Quite clever conceptually.  I am a huge fan of on the fly hidden manipulation to achieve a specific goal.

Answer (score 1):

We found out that document.ready was not good enough so 300ms worked well:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        resizeHeightOfMyDiv();

        $(window).on("resize", function() {
            resizeHeightOfMyDiv();
        });
     }, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced the issue and solved it using a **ResizeObserver**. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver):

> Implementations should, if they follow the specification, invoke
> resize events before paint and after layout.

So basically the observer always fires after layout, thus we should be able to get the correct dimensions of the observed element.
As a bonus the observer already returns the dimensions of the element. Therefore we don't even need to call something like `offsetWidth` (even though it should work too)

```js
const myElement = $("<div>", {"text": "text string"});

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  const lastEntry = entries.pop();

  // alternatively use contentBoxSize here
  const width = lastEntry.borderBoxSize.inlineSize;
  const height = lastEntry.borderBoxSize.blockSize;

  resizeObserver.disconnect();

  console.log("width:", width, "height:", height);
});

resizeObserver.observe(myElement[0]);

$("body").append(myElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This can also we wrapped in a handy async function like this:

```js
function appendAwaitLayout(parent, element) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      resizeObserver.disconnect();
      resolve(entries);
    });

    resizeObserver.observe(element);

    parent.append(element);
  });
}

// call it like this
appendAwaitLayout(document.body, document.createElement("div")).then((entries) => {
  console.log(entries)
  // do stuff here ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% but I think that your problem is that the code called outside the function where you attach the elements doesn't recognize the newly created elements. A quick example:

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#container).html('<p style="width:200px">Lorem ipsum</p>');
        alert($('#container p').width()); // alerts 0
        $('#container p').html('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'); // if content doesn't change, it's clearly a problem of jquery not being able to bind the functions to your new elements
    });
</script>
```

If you can tell us what you're doing exactly we'll surely find a solution.

**LATER EDIT**

Now that you posted code, I can actually help. You need to run this code:

```
$('.box', boxOutput).each(function(i) {
    boxWidth += $(this).width(); /* this is where sometimes width returns 0 */
});
```

in the function in your ajax response function. Example:

```
$.get('script.php', function(data) {
    $('#elem').html(data);
    // your code for width()
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: posted code in original post. yeah i am afraid it somehow doesn't recognize the elements inside. kind of frustrating when it doesn't work those very few times. i could always use another way to get desired result - just never met anything like this before and am more interested in what's actually happening.

Comment: Hi Claudiu, I am not having the problem of not getting ajax response back. I am having some sort of a racing condition after / right during I put html in. Josh's solution seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
$('.box', boxOutput).each(function(i) {
   //boxWidth += $(this).width(); /* this is where sometimes width returns 0 */
   boxWidth += this..getBoundingClientRect().width;
});
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

- If the element is an image, then the `width()` and `height()` methods should be accessed on the `.load()` jQuery handler;
- If the element is a DOM subtree, then they should be accessed on the `.ready()` handler.

The reason is that you can't rely on what jQuery reports to be the size of the element until the element has actually been loaded.